# Windows Phone button style

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How can I enlarge the font size of button caption in Windows Phone 7? I cannot see any FontSizep property, neither setting style seem to work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `FontSize` ...

```
<Button Content="I am a BIG Button" FontSize="50"/>
```